# SQL script to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, performance, entity-framework, linq

I would need some help with transforming a SQL script to Linq.
There are 2 huge tables. 
One with information about which company the user is in. and the other with when he logged in, and to which application.
What i need is all login records for users in a specific company and some information about the user itself.

My SQL query looks like this and perform really well.

```
SELECT 
UserLog.[ApplicationTypeId] AS [ApplicationTypeId], 
UserCompany.[EmployeeId] AS [EmployeeId], 
UserCompany.[LastLoggedOn] AS [LastLoggedOn], 
UserCompany.[ICalLastAccessedOn] AS [ICalLastAccessedOn], 
CASE WHEN ((UserLog.[Success] IS NOT NULL) AND (UserLog.[Success] = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [C1]
FROM  
(select Enabled, CompanyId, EmployeeId, Userid, LastLoggedOn, ICalLastAccessedOn from UserCompany  WHERE [Enabled] = 1 AND CompanyId = CompanyId) AS UserCompany
LEFT JOIN 
(select * from [dbo].[UserLog] AS [Extent2] where [Extent2].[LoginDateTime] >= '2017-01-04 00:00:00' and [CompanyId] = CompanyId) as UserLog
ON UserCompany.[UserId] = UserLog.[UserId]
```

My attempt at C# looks like this and performs really bad.

```
var loginRecordsByEmployee = (
from uc in 
    (from userCompany in _repository.UserCompanies.FindAll()
     where userCompany.Enabled && userCompany.CompanyId == _user.CompanyId
     select new { userCompany.EmployeeId, userCompany.LastLoggedOn, userCompany.ICalLastAccessedOn, userCompany.UserId }) 
join ul in 
    (from log in _repository.UserLogs.FindAll()
     where log.LoginDateTime >= fromDate && log.CompanyId == _user.CompanyId
     select new { log.UserId , log.ApplicationTypeId, log.Success}) 
on uc.UserId equals  ul.UserId
select new
{
    uc.EmployeeId,
    uc.LastLoggedOn,
    uc.ICalLastAccessedOn,
    ul.ApplicationTypeId,
    Success = ul.Success.HasValue && ul.Success.Value ? 1 : 0
}).ToList();
```

The query entity framework generates is using INNER JOIN and adds the WHERE after the join instead of filtering each select.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent2].[ApplicationTypeId] AS [ApplicationTypeId], 
[Extent1].[EmployeeId] AS [EmployeeId], 
[Extent1].[LastLoggedOn] AS [LastLoggedOn], 
[Extent1].[ICalLastAccessedOn] AS [ICalLastAccessedOn], 
CASE WHEN (([Extent2].[Success] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Success] = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[UserCompany] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserLog] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[UserId]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Enabled] = 1) AND ([Extent1].[CompanyId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[LoginDateTime] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent2].[CompanyId] = @p__linq__2)',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='EF9DB139-1C72-452F-BE88-6315E44DC2ED',@p__linq__1='2017-01-04 00:00:00',@p__linq__2=CompanyId
```

Is it possible to write specific queries in LINQ to SQL or would something like Dapper be my only way?
Any help is appreciated and feel free if you happen to see any performance issues or other approaches.

Comment: http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx take a look at this

Comment: MSDN Perform Left Outer Joins : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: if you want a left join use `DefaultIfEmpty`. And is there a reason you are nesting your select statements before joining them. Can you not simply do the left join and add your `where` clause

Comment: Something like this should do the trick: `(from uCompany in _repository.UserCompanies
 from uLog in _repository.UserLogs.Where(x=>x.UserId==uCompany.UserId).DefaultIfEmpty()
where ..
select new {...}).ToList();`

Comment: A 'why linq beats sql' article by someone who only understands basic SQL. There are some good points in that article but many that miss the point or display an incomplete understanding of the language

Comment: Are you sure the posted SQL query is the real one? I see some meaningless conditions like `CompanyId = CompanyId` and `[CompanyId] = CompanyId` inside, also it lacks parameters.

Comment: Yes, and `[Extent2]` is what LINQ has a habit of aliasing with

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you great comments.
I came up with this LINQ based on your input.

```
    var loginRecordsByEmployee = (
from uc in _repository.UserCompanies.FindAll()
    join ul in _repository.UserLogs.FindAll() on uc.UserId equals ul.UserId into uls
    from log in uls.Where(u => u.LoginDateTime >= fromDate && u.CompanyId == _user.CompanyId).DefaultIfEmpty()
where uc.Enabled && uc.CompanyId == _user.CompanyId
select new
{
  uc.EmployeeId,
  uc.LastLoggedOn,
  uc.ICalLastAccessedOn,
  ApplicationTypeId = log == null ? 0 : log.ApplicationTypeId,
  Success = log != null && log.Success.HasValue && log.Success.Value ? 1 : 0,
  HasLog = log != null
}).ToList();
```

Which results in this query and has adequate performance.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[EmployeeId] AS [EmployeeId], 
[Extent1].[LastLoggedOn] AS [LastLoggedOn], 
[Extent1].[ICalLastAccessedOn] AS [ICalLastAccessedOn], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[UserLogId] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent2].[ApplicationTypeId] END AS [C2], 
CASE WHEN (([Extent2].[UserLogId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Success] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Success] = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [C3], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[UserLogId] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C4]
FROM  [dbo].[UserCompany] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[UserLog] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[UserId]) AND ([Extent2].[LoginDateTime] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[CompanyId] = @p__linq__1)
WHERE ([Extent1].[Enabled] = 1) AND ([Extent1].[CompanyId] = @p__linq__2)',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__2 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='2017-01-04 00:00:00',@p__linq__1='EF9DB139-1C72-452F-BE88-6315E44DC2ED',@p__linq__2='EF9DB139-1C72-452F-BE88-6315E44DC2ED'
```